# URL (sitename.dev) instead of localhost/sitename

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-12.04, hosts

I wanted to use *http://projectname.dev* to access my local project in local machine. Now I'm using *localhost/projectname*. In my Ubuntu12.04 machine I tried editing the */etc/hosts* file like the following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myname-desktop
127.0.1.1/projectname       myname.projectname.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**127.0.1.1/projectname       myname.projectname.dev** is what I appended to the hosts. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Even after restarting my xampp server after the changes, I'm not able to access my localproject using **myname.projectname.dev** but it is still accessible in **localhost/projectname**. How do I achieve this? or What I did wrong and how can I resolve?

Comment: put myname.projectname.dev for ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: thanks for the response, now I understand where I went wrong. Instead of 127.0.0.1, I used 127.0.1.1/projectname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of googling and community help I found the solution. Maybe helpful to someone looking the same as I did.

First you have to edit  /etc/hosts file like below

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myname-desktop
127.0.0.1       myname.projectname.dev
```

Secondly, /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file has to be edited like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectname"
    ServerName myname.projectname.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/myname.projectname.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/myname.projectname.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally in the xampp config file located in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf, you have to uncomment the use of httpd-vhosts.conf file just by removing # in front of that.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Now you are good to go. Make sure to restart the server once after making all the changes

Answer (score 0):

I use windows and xampp, but you may try this solution.

first, edit your

> /xampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/your-project-name"
    ServerName your-project-name.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/your-project-name.localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/your-project-name.localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

secondly, go to

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc >

and open the

> hosts

file with your text editor. **Make sure to run your editor as an administrator, else it will not allow you save he changes**

Append this the following the bottom  of the file

> 127.0.0.1    your-project-name.localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1    www.your-project-name.localhost

**NB:** i used .localhost because it flows with all browsers. Recent chrome enforces certificate on .dev and .test, hencce blocking access.